# Making off-canvas sliding menu with css

Tags: html, css, slidingmenu

I want to make a sliding menu using solely CSS. The menu will reveal a list of items and a close button inside it. I currently have an anchor tag on my homepage that is styled correctly, but it does not do anything when clicked.

HTML:

```
<body class="homepage body-push">

    <!-- Menu -->
<nav class="menu" id="theMenu">
    <div class="menu-wrap">
        <h1 class="logo"><a href="#home">Focus</a></h1>
        <i class="icon-remove menu-close"></i>
        <a href="#home">Home</a>
        <a href="#services">Services</a>
        <a href="#process">Process</a>
        <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
        <a href="#about-us">About</a>
        <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-dribbble"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Menu button -->
    <div id="menuToggle"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>
</nav>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
position: fixed;
right: -200px;
width: 260px;
height: 100%;
top: 0;
z-index: 10;
text-align: left;

}
.menu.menu-open {
    right: 0px;
}

.menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 60px;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu a {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #808080;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu a > i {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: left;
    width: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 25px 2px;
}

.menu-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #808080;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-close:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

/* Push the body after clicking the menu button */
.body-push {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.body-push-toright {
    left: 200px;
}

.body-push-toleft {
    left: -200px;
}

.menu,
.body-push {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
         -o-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
}

#menuToggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

#menuToggle:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

UPDATE: I finally found a way to get it working.

HTML:

```
<!-- Menu -->
    <nav class="menu" id="theMenu">
        <div class="menu-wrap">
            <h1 class="logo"><a href="#">Menu</a></h1>
            <i class="icon-remove menu-close"></i>
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#services">Services</a>
            <a href="#process">Process</a>
            <a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            <a href="#about-us">About</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
            <a href="www.facebook.com"><i class="icon-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="www.twitter.com"><i class="icon-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="www.dribbble.com"><i class="icon-dribbble"></i></a>
            <a href="mailto:youremail@domain.com"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Menu button -->
        <div id="menuToggle"><i class="icon-reorder"></i></div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    position: fixed;
    right: -200px;
    width: 260px;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10;
    text-align: left;
}

.menu.menu-open {
    right: 0px;
}

.menu-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 60px;
    background: #1a1a1a;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
}

.menu h1.logo a {
    font-family: 'Raleway', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 800;
    letter-spacing: 0.15em;
    line-height: 40px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.menu h1.logo a:hover {
    color: #f85c37;
}

.menu img.logo {
    margin: 20px 0;
    max-width: 160px;
}

.menu a {
    margin-left: 20px;
    color: #808080;
    display: block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 40px;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu a:active {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.menu a > i {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    text-align: left;
    width: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 40px;
    margin: 25px 2px;
}

.menu-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #808080;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    top: 20px;
    right: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-close:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

/* Push the body after clicking the menu button */
.body-push {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}

.body-push-toright {
    left: 200px;
}

.body-push-toleft {
    left: -200px;
}

.menu,
.body-push {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
       -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
        -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
         -o-transition: all .3s ease;
            transition: all .3s ease;
}

#menuToggle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 11;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}

#menuToggle:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
            transition: all .1s ease-in-out;
}
```

Javascript:

```
    // Menu settings
    $('#menuToggle, .menu-close').on('click', function(){
        $('#menuToggle').toggleClass('active');
        $('body').toggleClass('body-push-toleft');
        $('#theMenu').toggleClass('menu-open');
    });

    // Scrollable menu on small devices
    $(window).bind("load resize", function(){
        if($(window).height() < 400){
            $(".menu").css("overflow-y","scroll");
        }
        else {
            $(".menu").css("overflow-y","hidden");
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend reading this: http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-sliding-menu/

If the article is TL;DR then use

```
/* Revealing 3D Menu CSS */
body
{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #221;
}

/* main page */
article
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 70%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 30px 15%;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    -o-transform-origin: 0 50%;
    transform-origin: 0 50%;
}


article:after
{
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    left: 100%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(right, rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0%, transparent 100%);
    pointer-events: none;
}

/* navigation */
nav
{
    position: fixed;
    left: -16em;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #654;
    border-right: 50px solid #765;
    box-shadow: 4px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav:after
{
    position: absolute;
    content: ' ';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -70px;
    top: 50%;
    border-width: 15px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #765;
}

nav ul
{
    width: 14em;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 1em;
}

nav a:link, nav a:visited
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 2.5em;
    text-indent: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    outline: 0 none;
}

nav a:hover, nav a:focus
{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #543;
    text-shadow: 0 0 4px #fff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

/* hovering */
article, article:after, nav, nav *
{
    -webkit-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 600ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 600ms ease;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
}

nav:hover
{
    left: 0;
}

nav:hover ~ article
{
    -webkit-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg);
    -moz-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg);
    -ms-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg);
    -o-transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg);
    transform: translateX(16em) perspective(600px) rotateY(10deg);
}

nav:hover ~ article:after
{
    left: 60%;
}
```

This can be used to create a 3d sliding menu as seen [here](http://blogs.sitepointstatic.com/examples/tech/css3-sliding-menu/index.html)

Comment: I'm looking more for the menu used on sites such as squarespace.com

Comment: IDK, maybe you could edit the CSS I provided so it doesn't travel on the Z axis and then just add it then. That'd be a bit cool, adding a menu on the side when you hover over it. But that's just my opinion.

Comment: Interesting.. I'll look at what I can do.

Comment: Yes, I was, I am going to update the OP now, in case anyone else wants to know.